# Azure AD B2C edit attributes

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

In Azure AD B2C, I notice that into the Page UI customization for a policy, we can include some HTML code into the input field for text labels when we edit attribute (in the picture example for chekbox). Do you think it's a potential hack and Microsoft will block this behavior or is it an expected case ?

[image: screenshot edit attribute]

Comment: I think this is a potential hack. This is an UI configuration, not API relevant operation. It defines the UI elements clearly on the UI, and only needs user to enter the value in text, not the code. If you need to change the style for UI elements, you can use the custom page, which allows you to design the page, the customize the UI elements based on your requirements.

Comment: OK for the style, I already use custom html page with css, but I am still not able to add a html link in the form, in order, for example, to manage the privacy policy approval ...

Comment: You can refer to the sample HTML and CSS content from the article - [Azure Active Directory B2C: Customize the Azure AD B2C user interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ability to add HTML code in the input field for text labels/values is not intended to be a feature and not the intended approach to achieve UI customization. You should not rely on this as validation that prevents this can be added at any point.

To customize the UI today, you can provide your own page with a div container where Azure AD B2C will display its controls. You can certainly use CSS to further customize the look and feel of these fields. Check out [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization) for more info.

Azure AD B2C is also looking at adding support for custom JS which will give you further control over the UI. You can vote for [that item](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15493536-add-support-for-javascript-inside-the-custom-ui-br) in the Azure AD B2C UserVoice forum to support it and stay up to date on its progress

Comment: OK thanks, what is the expected release date for this custom JS feature ?